# Complete latency for topology and spouts always zero in UI

Tags: apache-storm

The complete latency for the topology and spout is always coming zero. Also acker is coming zero. The number of acked for bolts are coming fine. I am using storm 1.1.1. My topology is reading text file and classifiying text using Naive Bayes in distributed environment of Apache storm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to anchor the tuples in order to be able to track the latency:

http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.6/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html